# Can each developer in a team use their own upload key for updating an app on the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, signing, google-play-console, software-distribution

I've been added to a team with access to manage the app, but when I try to upload an update it tells me that it has been signed with the wrong key.

As far as I understand it the Upload key is just to authenticate the developer, and google will re-sign the app for distribution using the key they manage securely (at least when the app is enrolled for this and it is indicated on the Release Keys page with the message "App Signing by Google Play is enabled for this app" at the top).

Is there somewhere where google manages a list of authorised upload keys for each app?  I imagine not because the error doesn't say "Not Authorised" - it says "Not the same key as what was used previously".

Which means either the team members needs to share their key around or else use a C.I tool (which will then hold the only signing key)

What am I overlooking here?